# css error - adding a banner messes up the scrollbar of the page

Tags: css, sharepoint-2010

hi
I have this simple CSS code to add a banner to a sharepoint 2010 site - the problem is, when I add it, the page doesn't 'recognize' the additional horizontal space added by the banner, and thus the scrollbar scrolls past the bottom of the page. This happens when windows is maximized as well as when it isn't. Happens in IE, chrome, FF.

EDIT: [screenshot of browser scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qm0PM.png)

banner code:

```
<div id="header_container">

</div>
```

css:

```
#header_container {
    background-image:url('/Images/topBanner.png'); 
    background-repeat:no-repeat; 
    background-color:#fff; 
    height:147px;
}
```

Comment: "sharepoint 2010" << thats your problem right there! Sorry, not very constructive, but had to be said.

Comment: Can you code this up on jsfiddle and include some images. Also maybe a screen shot of whats currently happening.

Comment: Ok just edited with an image of what's happening.

Comment: Steve Ballmer says there is nothing wrong with Sharepoint2010, you're coding it wrong.. try coding it differently for better recep.. err results.

Comment: Two useless comments, nothing constructive said. I am disappoint.

Comment: Are you able to put a your code up on jsfiddle.net for us to have a play with. It does seem quite weird - your css doesn't look wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding 1px padding and set the width. Im just learning but ive found sometimes wierd stuff happens when you add more code to a site. The 1px of padding has fixed some of my layouts

Also id recommend not using header_container as your div tag. Think about how many items you have in the header.

EG if i had a banner and site name but still needed a wrapping div i would use

```
<div id="header">
<div id="banner"></div>
<div id="headerlogo"></div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="headerbox">
<div id="banner"></div>
<div id="sitetitle"></div>
</div>
```